# How to implement correlation kernel for image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I read a paper that said about correlation kernel that defined:
W(x−y)=(α/1+d(|y−x|))
where α=(∫(1+d(y−x)dy)−1, (d(|y−x|)) is spatial Euclidean distance from the central pixel. 
Given an image I. Could you help me implement convolution that kernel with the image by matlab code. Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What are `x` and what are `y`?  That equation doesn't make any sense.  Also, pointing us to this paper that shows this formula would help.

Comment: I found your post on Signal Processing Exchange: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683970/how-to-implement-correlation-kernel-for-image.  That `-1` is actually **raised to the power**.  StackOverflow does not support LaTeX editing.  Also `\alpha` is incorrectly balanced with the parantheses.  Can you please edit the equation so that it's correct?  Also what is `d(y-x)` in comparison to `d(|y-x|)`?

Comment: So `d(y-x)` is the same as `d(|y-x|)`? I found the article and they're not very clear on this either.

Comment: Yes sir, I think it is same. It maybe the L1 distance. Do you have any idea to implement it?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be a problem.  I'll make a post.

Comment: @rayryeng This link you posted links to this question, not to [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/). Are you sure that is what you meant?

Comment: @user8264 - Sorry got busy. I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: @kkuilla. Oops sorry. You're right. I'll post the actual link in another comment

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17289/what-is-correlation-kernel-and-compare-with-gaussian-kernel

Comment: @user8264 - I'm done.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK! Sorry for the delay.  Referencing the paper, the convolution kernel can be written as:

[image: eqn1]

`d(|y-x|)` is the Euclidean distance between the centre pixel `y` and a location in the kernel `x`.  `\alpha` is used to ensure that the entire area under the kernel is 1.  However, you did not specify how **big** this kernel is.  As such, we will specify the rows and columns of this kernel to be `M` and `N` respectively.  Let's also assume that the size of the kernel for each dimension is **odd**.  The reason why is because the shape of the kernel will be an even square and makes implementation easier.  As such, here are the steps that I would perform to do this:

1. Define a grid of `X` and `Y` co-ordinates, and ensure that the centre pixel is at 0.
2. Compute each term in the convolution kernel **without** the `\alpha` term.
3. Sum up all of the terms in the kernel, then divide every value in this kernel by this term so that the entire area of the kernel is 1.

Let's do this step by step:

## Step #1

We can do this by using [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html).  `meshgrid` (in this case) creates a 2D grid of `(X,Y)` co-ordinates.  `X` defines the horizontal co-ordinate for each location in `X`, while `Y` defines this vertically. By calling `meshgrid(1:m, 1:n)`, I am creating a `n x m` grid for both `X` and `Y`, where each row of `X` progresses from 1 to `m`, while each column of `Y` progresses from 1 to `n`.  Therefore, these will both be `n x m` matrices.  Calling the above with `m = 4` and `n = 4` computes:

```
m = 4;
n = 4;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:m, 1:n)

X =

 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4

Y =

 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4
```

As such, we simply have to modify this, but we ensure that the centre is at `(0,0)`, and also ensure that the size of `X` and `Y` are odd.  Let's say that `M = 5` and `N = 5`.  We can then define our `X` and `Y` co-ordinates like so:

```
M = 5;
N = 5;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-floor(N/2):floor(N/2), -floor(M/2):floor(M/2))

X =

-2    -1     0     1     2
-2    -1     0     1     2
-2    -1     0     1     2
-2    -1     0     1     2
-2    -1     0     1     2


Y =

-2    -2    -2    -2    -2
-1    -1    -1    -1    -1
 0     0     0     0     0
 1     1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2     2
```

As you can see here, the centre pixel for both `X` and `Y` are defined as `(0,0)`.  Everywhere else has its `(X,Y)` co-ordinates defined **with respect to the centre**.

## Step #2

We simply have to compute the Euclidean distance between the centre pixel to every point in the kernel.  This can be done by:

```
dis = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2)

dis =

2.8284    2.2361    2.0000    2.2361    2.8284
2.2361    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142    2.2361
2.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000    2.0000
2.2361    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142    2.2361
2.8284    2.2361    2.0000    2.2361    2.8284
```

Doing some quick calculation checks, you can see that this agrees with our understanding of Euclidean distance.  Moving to the left by 1 from the centre is a distance of 1.  Moving to the left by 1 then up by 1 gives us a Euclidean distance of `\sqrt(1^2 + 1^2) = \sqrt(2) = 1.4142`.  Doing similar checks with each element will demonstrate that this is indeed a Euclidean distance field from the centre pixel.  After we do this, let's compute the kernel terms **without** the `\alpha` term.

```
kern = 1 ./ (1 + dis)

kern =

0.2612    0.3090    0.3333    0.3090    0.2612
0.3090    0.4142    0.5000    0.4142    0.3090
0.3333    0.5000    1.0000    0.5000    0.3333
0.3090    0.4142    0.5000    0.4142    0.3090
0.2612    0.3090    0.3333    0.3090    0.2612
```

## Step #3

The last step we need is to normalize the mask so that the total sum of the kernel is 1.  This can simply be done by:

```
kernFinal = kern / sum(kern(:))

kernFinal =

0.0275    0.0325    0.0351    0.0325    0.0275
0.0325    0.0436    0.0526    0.0436    0.0325
0.0351    0.0526    0.1052    0.0526    0.0351
0.0325    0.0436    0.0526    0.0436    0.0325
0.0275    0.0325    0.0351    0.0325    0.0275
```

This should finally give you the correlation kernel that you are seeking.  You can now use this in convolution (i.e. using `imfilter` or `conv2`).

---

Hopefully I have answered your question adequately.  Good luck!

Comment: It looks like high pass filter, right? What is purpose of that filter comparison with low pass filter (Ex: Gaussian filter)

Comment: @user8264 - No, I'd say this is more of a low-pass filter.  I honestly have no idea why this would be preferred over a Gaussian filter.  Perhaps something to do with the way the frequency response looks like?

Comment: I check it, I did not see any advantage of this method compare with gaussian filter. They are similar. But when I draw the shape of each filter, the gaussian filter looks like low pass filter, and the above filter looks like high pass filter.

Comment: @user8264 - Again, I don't think so.  Create a 5 x 5 Gaussian mask using `fspecial` using any sigma you wish.  You'll see that the distribution of the points is more or less than same as what you see with the correlation filter.